# Using OIKWAN usb-c to ethernet cable on catalina

Tags: usb, ethernet

I bought this cable

[https://www.amazon.com/USB-C-Cisco-Console-Cable-Windows/dp/B0774JV2QQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0774JV2QQ)

and installed FTDI drivers

and the system profiler does pick it up:

```
FT232R USB UART:

  Product ID:   0x6001
  Vendor ID:    0x0403  (Future Technology Devices International Limited)
  Version:  6.00
  Serial Number:    A91UIYBK
  Speed:    Up to 12 Mb/s
  Manufacturer: FTDI
  Location ID:  0x14400000 / 1
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    90
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

and i even turned on the kext

```
 kextstat| grep FTDI
  154    0 0xffffff7f84653000 0x7000     0x7000     com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver (2.4.4) B137605C-32D8-3E81-89B6-E1F8039FC427 <88 64 6 5 3 1>%
```

but when I have the cable connected from the macbook to the router, no USB connection for internet comes up in the network profile under system network preferences.

Not sure what else to do

Comment: Did you click the + button and drop down the list of Interfaces? You might need to manually add it.

Comment: There are other USB-C to Ethernet devices that do not require installing drivers and certainly nothing with a kernel extension.  Specifically used both StarTech ones and HP USB-C to RJ45 PN: 855474-001 manf by LUXSHARE-ICT.  Just plug them in and they work without any configuration.

Comment: Did you go to System Preferences -> Security -> General and click Allow on the kernel extension?

Comment: darn - I made the assumption that RJ45 always meant ethernet - Allan's answer is quite amazing - but my router doesn't expose console, so I think will just need to buy another cable, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re not going to find it in Networking, because it’s a [Cisco console cable](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/7000-series-routers/12223-14.html) and USB to [RS-232 UART](https://www.circuitbasics.com/basics-uart-communication/) all-in-one.   The Cisco console cable is a serial cable, with a DB-9 on one end and an RJ-45 connector on the other - ***it’s not Ethernet.***

You will need an application like [`screen` (comes with macOS), Minicom or iTterm2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/318280/119271)  that allows you to connect to the serial console.  Most importantly, when you plug it into the router, you cannot plug it into any of the network ports - you need to plug it into the console port.

[image]

Comment: damnit - I thought RJ-45 always meant ethernet - looking at your other answer - so once I have screen working, then internet will flow or i stil need to do more on system prefernces?

Comment: Argh... I completely missed the "Cisco Console Cable" on the URL... Good catch @Allan

Comment: ah - darn - this consumer modem doesn't expose a console connection - i will need to get another adaptor as James posted- thanks ya'll

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian No.  This cable is designed to connect to the *management* port of the switch/router.  It's not a network cable.  You need a [USB-C to Ethernet adapter](https://amzn.to/3lbmwEQ) (I use this exact one)  to connect to the network for internet access

Comment: Also...make sure you have a quality [Ethernet cable](https://amzn.to/2Yqsvfw) to go from the adapter to the router.  It probably came with one and should work just fine, but putting this here just in case.